# Win8 /Metro - Picture is being edited by another person

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am taking a picture and saving it to disk.  The picture actually gets to disk, but it is not being closed because when I try and open it by clicking on it in Windows Explorer, I get the message:

> "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the Picture is
>   being edited by another person"

Here is the code, how should I close the stream/file?

```
var ui = new CameraCaptureUI();
ui.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3);
StorageFile file = await ui.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(stream);
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
var result = await file.CopyAsync(storageFolder, "tps2.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out
[.Net Metro Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

According to it, you should wrap your stream with a using clause or call Dispose, instead of calling Close.
This didn't work for me, but maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked and haven't found the answer. Presumably because the release is a "developer preview" it's well below release quality and there are many bits of functionality that are missing or broken. As managing system resources such as files is crucial we will presumably see more & better functionality with the next ("consumer preview") release, which is only 2 days away as I write this.

**Edit:**
Good news, with the consumer preview tools (Win8 beta) IRandomAccessStream implements IDisposable. That's the result type of the OpenAsync operation on StorageFile.